# image right text in middle on the same line but middle to the whole design

Tags: html, css

Can any help me to bring the next to the middle from the whole line with the Image.  right now the text is in middle from the Image to the left border..

**CSS:**

```
#cen {
    max-width: 1006px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    height: 80px;
    float: right
}
h1 {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 34px
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <div id=cen>
            <a title="test" href=http://www.test.m/>
              <img src=pic/pic2.png alt="test" 
                    title="test" height=80 width=142>
            </a>
            <h1>this is a test and test</h1>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Looking for something Like this :

```
table,tr{
```

width:100%;

```
}
#cen {
    max-width: 1006px;
    margin: 3px 8px 2px 15px;
    height: 80px;
     width:100%;
     border:1px solid red;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
a,h1{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i have found a way.
but the Image is not on the right place it sit now on the left side

i can not find how it works when it sit right. here is the new Version:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/keLacL9v/5/)

both variations are there